# Realtime database - index and orderByChild

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In a chat application, I have this RTDB structure:

```
chats: {
  $roomId: {
    $messageId: {
      senderId: "..."
      message: "..."
    }
  }
}
userRooms: {
  $uid: {
    $roomId: {
      "message: "..."
      "time": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to order my userRooms by 'time' (which is a String, e.g: "2023-03-05 07:24:54.075539").

My rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "userRooms": {
        ".indexOn": ["time"]
    }
  }
}
```

With Flutter, my DatabaseReference is:

```
String uid = "...";
DatabaseReference userRooms = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .ref('userRooms/$uid')
        .orderByChild('time')
        .ref;
```

But I don't know if I really need to do `orderByChild` ?
Are my rules correct ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In these lines, you build a `Query` and then extract the original `DatabaseReference` object (without the query filters).

```
DatabaseReference userRooms = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .ref('userRooms/$uid')
        .orderByChild('time')
        .ref;
```

Additionally, you need to put the `uid` into the reference when building it:

```
.ref('userRooms/' + uid)
```

Instead of assigning it to a `DatabaseReference`, assign to a `Query` instead:

```
Query sortedUserRoomsQuery = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .ref('userRooms/' + uid)
        .orderByChild('time');
```